# What section of mvc project called when user redirect from another site to this site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I implement shop in my website .After select products I redirect user to bank url. After purchase bank redirect user to my website when I debug found that bank **numbers** redirect user to my web site because I put breakpoint into action that user come back to it after purchase in bank.

I put  breakpoint into `Global.asax.cs` and `RegisterRoutes` but after redirect to my website called specific  action only.

Is my reasoning correct?

Is my test right?

Comment: I did not understand why you want to use global.asax events ? why dont you get the query string value inside the mvc action code directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `Application_AcquireRequestState()` Event in `Global.asax.cs`.

**`Application_AcquireRequestState()`** – This event raised just before session-specific data is retrieved for the client and is used to populate Session Collection for current request.

**Example:**

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        bool redirected = false; 
        if ( !redirected)
        {
             var routeData = urlHelper.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(currentContext);
            if (routeData != null)
            {
                var action = routeData.Values["action"] as string;
                var controller = routeData.Values["controller"] as string;
                if (controller != null && controller.ToLower() != "login" && controller.ToLower() != "manage")
                {
                    var baseUrl = "http://localhost/"+ "home/Index";
                     Response.Redirect(baseUrl);
                }
            }
            else{
              Response.Redirect("~/Home/index");
            }

        }

}
```

You can find more information form [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/looking-inside-global-asax-application-file-in-Asp-Net-3-5/) and [this](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/what-is-use-of-globalasax-file-in.html) link.

Hopefully it's help for you.

Comment: I use number bank  for sale products. Each bank redirect user to another action

Comment: you can pass query parameter. is it enough answer? is not then explain briefly what you exactly want? Like what is ` another action`